# Use ImageMagick to create mockups like placeit.net?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I would like to combine to images with ImageMagick.

I tried this code:

```
composite fill.png cover.png -compose dst-atop -matte final.png
```

But I will make somethink similar to [placeit.net](http://placeit.net). Are there ImageMagick functions. Could you please give an example?

Comment: I am not sure which mockup you want.. But see http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tshirt/index.php and http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php and http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/outfit/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
convert background.png overlay.png -geometry +10+10 -composite result.png
```

+10+10 are the coordinates that indicate the offset of the overlay from the top left corner.